# Jenkins: How to create pipeline to clone local repository in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Two local Git repositories named 'Springboot application' and 'Web application' which contains the source code of Maven Springboot application and a Maven Web application are given in the path "/home/Labuser/Desktop/Project/Jenkinspipeline software engineering".

Getting Started,

Jenkins and Tomcat is already present inside the environment.

Login to Jenkins with the Username and Password as "admin"

Create a Pipeline Job named 'Release pipeline'

and configure it with a declarative pipeline script to clone the "Springboot application" repository

How to create a pipeline and configure to clone local git repository to it

Jenkins: How to create pipeline to clone local repository in Jenkins